# linkage fails when referencing a constructor

Tags: c++, gcc, ld

I have two source files, in one of them there's a static member from my own class, foo. When I compile it to an object file, the compiler generates a .ctors section, and within it, a function that calls the constructor, lets call it _GLOBAL__SUB_I_FOO.

In the second source file, I try to call this constructor myself:

```
int _GLOBAL__SUB_I_FOO();
int bar(){
   _GLOBAL__SUB_I_FOO();
}
```

And when I'm linking those two objects, there's an undefined reference to _GLOBAL__SUB_I_FOO from the second file.
When I'm linking using --relocatable to view what went wrong, I can see that the original constructor was renamed to _GLOBAL__SUB_I_FOO_0 to avoid the "collision" (which is intentional). What can I do to fix it?
I'm using gcc 7.3.0

Comment: Why not just call the constructor (create an object)?

Comment: It's a constructor of a static object

Comment: Did the compiler create this function `_GLOBAL__SIB_I_FOO` or is that a function you wrote?

Comment: The compiler created it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101243/how-to-find-global-static-initializations

Comment: Although I would highly advise avoiding any non standard stuff

Comment: Why are you trying to call this function anyway? It seems to me like it's supposed to stay hidden as an implementation detail.

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash, this is an attempt to find this function, but I found it, it is not the problem, the problem is the linker changes its name because of a "collision" with another object file (that's what I suspect)

Comment: @SirGuy, It probably is supposed to stay hidden, but I have a special case where I need to call it myself, So how can I make it non-hidden? I tried to merge the .ctors with .text but it didn't work either.

Comment: Given that the name of the function is one reserved for the implementation, it is fairly clear that you are *not* supposed to call it yourself (even *if* you technically *can*).

Comment: But I want to, even though it's not standard.

Answer (score 0):

To execute the code that was previously in the constructor for the static object, move it into an `init()` function, and call that from the constructor (and from anywhere else you need it).

Comment: It is possible, but not the answer I am looking for, I'm looking for more hermetic solution that will let me call any ctor without having to implement it inside another function. But thanks, though.

Comment: The problem with static objects is that they are constructed, once, at a time determined by the implementation. It's one object and as such it can only be constructed once. Perhaps you'd get better mileage from something based on the `Singleton` pattern

Comment: If you want to know, I'm actually implementing the mechanism that invokes the constructors. Just.. go with me on this one, I know it isn't standard but there got to be a way to do it.

Comment: I don't think gcc 7.3.0  is compatible with "go with me on this". It's always going to pick a unique name for its internal function, and it's always going to do so _after_ any changes _you_ make to the code. And if by chance you do find a hack, maybe by putting in an adjacent object and jumping relative to its address, the hack is still prone to failure on any other compiler, or other version of that compiler. I just think that what you're trying to do... is wrong.

Comment: Are you saying this because you know, or that's your feeling? Because it's weird to me that the ld knows that this is an internal function - and if it knows, there must be a way to mark it as a "normal" function. I'm not looking for a hack, its just calling a function from a different object.

Comment: The initial underscore tells us it's an internal function. But so does the C++ standard. Construction of globals is determined by the implementation. 

I think perhaps the problem is that you're focussing on this compiler-generated function, and not on the constructor. The latter is a function written by you, and calling it isn't at all difficult. You can use placement new, yes?

Comment: I prefer to just iterate through .ctors and calls what's in there, because there is no list of static objects on which I can call placement new on.

Comment: If you want to run _all_ the constructors again, simply quit and re-run the program